# Проблема занесения строк в базу

Tags: php, html, mysql, multiple

Здравствуйте есть таблица в базе где я собираюсь хранить все жанры к определенному сериалу но есть проблема, я собираюсь сделать внос в базу данных сразу из сайта для этого я использую select multiple, логично что жанров для сериала больше одного и они все сохранены в int т.е values у каждого жанра это определенная цифра и в таблице жанры тоже должны сохранятся в int "Это я сделал для поиска по жанрам на сайте", ну так вот, я столкнулся с проблемой как же заносить жанры в таблицу так чтобы каждый новый жанр это новая строка в базе? просто если напрямую заносить в базу жанры то сохранятся там будет только последний выбранный жанр, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? может использовать while "Я еще не пробовал", вот код -

```
$janr = FormChars($_POST['janr']);//Проверка на вредоносные символы и только
mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "INSERT INTO `janrs` ( `jid`, `tid`) VALUES ($janr, Айди сериала тут)");
```

это html "select"

```
<select name="janr" id="janr" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="жанры"><option value="1">
                Альтернативная история
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                Альтернативная реальность
            </option>
            <option value="3">
                Ангелы
            </option>
            <option value="4">
                Андроиды
            </option>
            <option value="5">
                Антивойна
            </option>
            <option value="6">
                Антиутопия
            </option>
            <option value="7">
                Баскетбол
            </option>
            <option value="8">
                Безумие
            </option>
            <option value="9">
                Бисёнэн
            </option>
            <option value="10">
                Боевые искусства
            </option>
            <!--И т.д-->
</select>
```

Comment: Делаете таблицу "жанры". Делаете таблицу "фильмы". Делаете таблицу МногиеКоМногим, где будет id_фильма и id_жанра

Comment: хм не понял)Что именно надо в данном случае делать?

Comment: Циклом заносите каждую запись из `$_POST['janr']`

Comment: можно на примере показать?)я щас не выспавшийся))))

Comment: Ценный совет! Спать нужно нормально

Comment: как в данном случае должен выглядеть цикл?

Comment: Сколько можно одно и то же спрашивать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если Вы используете **select multiple** с PHP, то стоит в таком случае немного изменить атрибут "name", а именно

```
<select name="janr[]" id="janr" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="жанры"><option value="1">
...
```

Дальше, когда вы поймаете данный форму в скрипте, то получите массив выбранных значений, который можно будет уже обойти при помощи оператора *foreach*

```
$janrs = $_POST['janr'];
foreach ($janrs as $janr) {
    $jId = (int)$janr; // Поскольку айдишки в селекте это цифры, то лучше преобразовать их в цифры, и скорее всего в таблице данное поле типа INT
    $fid = Айди сериала;
    mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "INSERT INTO `janrs` (`jid`, `tid`) VALUES ($jId, $fid)");
}
```

Comment: Ну вот зачем новичкам советовать плохие запросы. Запрос должен выглядеть как минимум так `INSERT INTO janrs (jid, tid) VALUES (?, ?)`. А дальше работа с соответствующими методами `mysqli`

Comment: написано на языке новичка, если он решит использовать соответствующие методы mysqli, то переделает сам, а тут просто решение, без обработки ошибок, без конструкторов/деструкторов и прочей фигни типа FormChars()

Comment: ошибка в цикле for ($janrs *as* $janr){...}  В чем может быть ошибка? FormChars это проверка на вредоносные символы

Comment: какие нафиг вредоносные символы, если ты там ожидаешь число? Не проще ли его СРАЗУ в инт преобразовывать и потом проверять, если на выходе 0, то что-то пошло не так, иначе - добавляем ИНТОВОЕ значение.

Comment: все решил проблему циклом foreach

Comment: аххахах, ну че я за безопасность)

Comment: точно! foreach.... давно уже на пыхе не писал, сорян, но молодец что сам разобрался

Comment: Кстати... насчет "вредоносных" символов и базы данных. Не стоит использовать некие функции, которые непойми что делают, а использовать специально обученный для этого функционал, который работает куда быстрее и надежнее, чем нечто самопальное, а именно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: у меня в функции FormChars стоит обработчик function FormChars($p1, $p2 = 0)
{
    global $CONNECTDB;
    if ($p2) return mysqli_real_escape_string($CONNECTDB, $p1);
    else return nl2br(htmlspecialchars(trim($p1), ENT_QUOTES), false);
}

Comment: просто занес все это в функцию для удобного использования